# scala lift json: pattern match on unknown data?

Tags: json, scala, pattern-matching, lift, case-class

I have some strange json that I cannot change, and I wish to parse it using
the JsonParsen in lift.

A typical json is like:

> ```
>     {"name":"xxx",  "data":{
>         "data_123456":{"id":"Hello"},
>         "data_789901":{"id":"Hello"},
>         "data_987654":{"id":"Hello"},  
> }}
> ```

The issue is that the keys for the data are unknown (data_xxxxx, where the xx:s 
are not known).
This is bad json, but I have to live with it.

How am I supposed to setup case-classes in scala to be able to build a proper
structure when the keys here are unknown, but the structure is known?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Map, and every value can be JValue too, representing unparsed JSON. Example:

```
case class Id(id: String)
case class Data(name: JValue, data: Map[String, Id])
```

And then:

```
json.extract[Data]
res0: Data(JString(xxx),Map(data_123456 -> Id(Hello), data_789901 -> Id(Hello), data_987654 -> Id(Hello)))
```